# Electron: run shell commands with arguments

Tags: shell, electron

I'm building an electron app,

I can run shell commands pretty easily with the shell api (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell)

This command runs perfect for example:

```
shell.openItem("D:\test.bat");
```

This one does not

```
shell.openItem("D:\test.bat argument1");
```

How to run electron shell command with arguments?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`shell.openItem` isn't designed for that. 
Use the `spawn` function of NodeJS from the `child_process` core module.

```js
let spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

let bat = spawn("cmd.exe", [
    "/c",          // Argument for cmd.exe to carry out the specified script
    "D:\test.bat", // Path to your file
    "argument1",   // First argument
    "argumentN"    // n-th argument
]);

bat.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    // Handle data...
});

bat.stderr.on("data", (err) => {
    // Handle error...
});

bat.on("exit", (code) => {
    // Handle exit
});
```

Comment: Does it require node installed or just npm dependency?

Comment: I mean, is "child_process"  only part of electron js ie: I don't need nodejs installed in client desktop ?

Comment: @SlimaneDeb `child_process` is part of NodeJS, not electron. It's a core module. See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Comment: @SlimaneDeb, to clarify NullDev's statement, electron by default bundles nodejs in its binary. So all core modules should be available to you.