# Angular & Electron - Execute external application

Tags: angular, electron

I'm beginning with electron & angular.

I'm trying to execute an external application.
Let's say pks.exe that is in c:\kube\

I did not find clearly if there is a way of doing that.
I tried with ngx-electron library.  I can open something like notepad or a word document using the openPath api.  But it has not the the aim of executing something (and even more with parameters) just opening a file, just like if I clicked twice on it.

I also saw people speaking of child_process.  But I don't managed to have it working with angular.  It seems it is only working with nodejs.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron: run shell commands with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328916/electron-run-shell-commands-with-arguments)

Comment: No this answer is aboout nodejs.  In my question I told it was not working wis angular.  When I compile it says something like unable to import child°process module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so basically to answer in a bit more detail:

Electrun is a multi process architecture. Basically, there are 2 processes, the `main processes` which is a nodeJS process and the `renderer process` which is a BrowserWindow running chromium. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#differences-between-main-process-and-renderer-process

Angular runs in the `renderer`. Since that is basically browser environment you can only perform javascript code that also works in a normal browser context. In a browser you can not perform scripts that directly open an application on your PC or something like a shell script. That would be a security nightmare (imagine visiting a website which could then execute arbitrary scripts on your PC. they could just run `rm -rf /` or open like e.g. 1000 instances of `word.exe`). You can indirectly open some apps with `mailto:` or `tel:` links etc...

Since the `main` process is running nodeJS, you can include standard nodeJS libraries like `child_process` https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html.

So to get stuff working for you:

In your code, you should forward the request to open the external application from the `renderer` (angular) process to the `main` (nodeJS) process. Checkout https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main and https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer on how to do that specifically.

Angular (some `service.ts` or `component.ts`)

```js
ipcRenderer.send('open_app', 'c:\kube\');
```

NodeJS process (`index.js` where you also create your initial BrowserWindow)

```js
ipcMain.on('open_app', (event, path) => {
    // path contains 'c:\kube\'
    child_process.spawn(path);
});
```

---

For completeness: You can also directly execute some `main` process functions from within the `renderer` via the `remote` module https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote. But I would suggest to keep the process individual code in the corresponding process and communicate only via IPC. This makes it easier to also support a standard webapp running without electron if you ever choose to deliver a webapp only.

Comment: Great... it's now clear for me.  And ... now it's working.  Many thanks.